# Let $\lim_{t\to t_0}\phi(t) = a$. Prove that $f(x) = \mathcal{o}(g(x)) \implies f(\phi(t)) = \mathcal{o}(g(\phi(t)))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics

> Let:
>   $$
> \lim_{t\to t_0}\phi(t) = a
> $$
>   where $\phi(t)\ne a$ and $t\ne t_0$ in the neighbourhood of $t_0$. Prove that:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> f(x) \stackrel{x\to x_0}{=} \mathcal{o}(g(x)) &\implies f(\phi(t)) \stackrel{t\to t_0}{=} \mathcal{o}(g(\phi(t)))\tag 1\\
> f(x) \stackrel{x\to x_0}{=} \mathcal{O}(g(x)) &\implies f(\phi(t)) \stackrel{t\to t_0}{=} \mathcal{O}(g(\phi(t)))\tag 2
> \end{align*}
> $$

I'm having difficulties with proving the above. I've started by writing down the definitions of what's given in the statement. First, we are given that:
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0}\phi(t) = a \iff \forall\epsilon>0\ \exists \delta_\epsilon > 0: |t-t_0| < \delta_\epsilon \implies |\phi(t) - a| < \epsilon
$$

Also $f(x)$ is asymptotically smaller than $g(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$, namely:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \iff \forall\epsilon>0\ \exists \delta_\epsilon > 0: |x-x_0| < \delta_\epsilon \implies \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| < \epsilon
$$

Using the above, I need to somehow arrive at the following:
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{f(\phi(t))}{g(\phi(t))} = 0
$$

The problem is I'm not sure where to start. Could someone please share some kind of sketch on how to proceed?

Comment: There's no relationship whatsoever between $a$ and $x_0$?

Comment: @Matteo Unfortunately no, this is how the problem stated in the book.

Comment: I think $a$ needs to be replaced by $x_0$. And then these results are trivial applications of rule of substitution for limits.

Comment: I agree with @ParamanandSingh. Without this assumption the statement is clearly false.